# Can a function be Surjective if all $y$ correspond to an $x$ but not all $x$ correspond to a $y$?

Tags: functions

Can a function be surjective such that $\forall y \in  Y$ there exists $x \in  X$ such that  $f(x) = y$ but such that not all $x$ values actually correspond to a $y$ value?

Comment: As long as every possible value of y is "corresponded to", then you have a surjective function. So in your case I would say your function is surjective.

Comment: @Kaynex now I have to contradicting answers? Your's and Cettt's answer?

Comment: The condition "not all $x$ correspond to some $y$" is in contradiction with the definition of function, which says that "all $x$ correspond to exactly one $y$".

Comment: @Crostul my function says that for all y there exist's and x such that f(x) = y but it doesn't say that for all x there exists a corresponding y? That's what I'm confused about?

Comment: What about the function $\ln(x)$? It is surjective on all real numbers, right? Or do we have to fix our domain to  the positive reals?

Comment: @Kaynex $\ln:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ is how the natural logarithm is defined. The domain can't be all of the reals, because $ln$ does not map the negatives to any real number. It's not defined there.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a surjective function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is by definition a map that takes all values $x\in X$ and sends it to exactly one value $f(x)\in Y$. So in short no. However, if $f:X\to Y$ is surjective it is possible (in some cases) to define a surjective function $g:Z\to Y$ where $Z\subsetneq X$ such that $g(z)=f(z) ~\forall z\in Z$. This function is not defined on all of $X$ and so there does exist a $x\in X$ such that $g(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: @K.M. well you haven't defined what your case is exactly. If your function is defined $f:X\to Y$ , then no, because this by definition means that the function $f$ maps every element of $X$ to some element of $Y$.

Comment: Is this the case in my specified function since my function states that for all y there is a corresponding x that yields f(x) but it doesn't specify that there is an f(x) for all x's?

Comment: @K.M. I think you are confusing injectivity, surjectivity and the definition of a function here. By definition of a function, if $x$ is in the domain of the function $f$, then there must be an element $y$ in the co-domain such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Right, so that applies to a surjective function too I assume?

Comment: @K.M. it applies to all functions. A surjective function is a function for which every element $y$ in the co-domain there exists an element $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$, which is the converse of my previous statement, which applies for all functions. A function is surjective if its co-domain equals its range.

Answer (score 2):

a function $f: X \to Y$ by definition assigns exactly one value $y=f(x) \in Y$ to all $x \in X$.

So, no it's not possible.